# Is there a good reason to use CassiniDev instead of VS WebServer?

Tags: .net, asp.net, webserver, cassini

I discover this WebServer to use with Visual Studio (http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/)

Anyone know if this is better than VS WebServer?

Comment: If you are comparing/choosing, you should also consider IIS Express. Or indeed: just use full IIS

Answer (score 6):

Use neither - instead use IIS express which is built upon the actual IIS binaries.

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/868/iis-express-overview/

Its far better than either.

Comment: can you qualify this with some reasons?

Comment: I did above - its built upon IIS the others arent so there inherently are differences : )  Cassini isn't built on those binaries and suffers from various issues including running in a different security context and doesn't support https either so the end testing result is different than the environment you will be running in. It also is notorious for not picking up changes while running and you change web app.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. I'm using cassinidev for system tests and i like the single process model they have for debugging. I'll be interested to see what debugging feels like.

Answer (score 5):

It looks to resolve some issues with the VS development server, but you should also investigate [IIS Express](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/868/iis-express-overview/) if you're going to be deploying on IIS. I've found it a pleasure to use, it solves many of the same issues and is integrated with Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

From project's web site:

> The goal of the CassiniDev project is to provide an open platform for
>   developing a robust ASP.Net web server implementation that addresses
>   many of the limitations and difficulties encountered when using
>   Cassini and/or Visual Studio Development Server.
>
> CassiniDev is packaged as a standalone WinForms GUI application, a
>   console application and library assembly suitable for self hosting and
>   in automated testing scenarios including continuous integration and as
>   a **100% compatible drop-in replacement for the Visual Studio 2008/2010
>   development server**.

so it should be at least as good as the default VS web server or better.

Being open source is an advantage but this also depends on how often it's updated and extended and on how big is the dev community...

Comment: yes, forgot to mention that anyway in general is a good approach to have development environment as close as possible to the production environment, this lead us to adopt IIS Express or IIS ( if available ), just to avoid integration issues on deployment...

Answer (score 1):

CassiniDev is based off of the integrated VS Web Server (called Cassini). The CodePlex version has many improvements but the question is whether you need those or not. Simply read the codeplex page and decide for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

IIS Express is 100% the best option if you are using VS 2010 or later, i still use CassiniDev when i need a quick ad-hoc server ie serving up html/docs quickly that use features that cant be run directly from the file system otherwise use IIS Express for .net based sites or Full IIS if absolutely needed.

Any .net functionality based on versions that incompatible with 4.0 will soon start to break ie. vNext, much of the upcoming rosalyn features in the new .net compilers,  anything requiring C#6  features etc. as these all require 4.6